# C# GetRange Wrapped

Tags: c#

I would like to ask if there is a similar method to List.GetRange(id,count) but wrapped. That accepts both positive and negative start id and count that exceeds the indexing. When collection is exceeded elements would be taken from start?

The only way I am thinking of is:

```
List<T> e = new List<T>{a,b,c,d,e,f};

int start=4%e.Count;
int n= 5;
List<T> eNew = new List<T>(n);


for (int i=start; i<start+n i++)
   eNew.Add(e[i%e.Count]);
```

Is there any existing similar built in command to do this or faster one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's such a method.  Certainly there'd have to be caution to ensure that such a function is expected to behave that way.  It would be bad for a coder to think she'd get an error if out of range but instead get a result.

But for your own convenience, you can create a generic extension method yourself.  I made one below.  Beyond your code that will loop over, this code will allow starting at a negative index.  Even beyond that, it will allow a negative length.

```
public static class MyExtensions {

    public static List<T> GetRingedRange<T> (
        this List<T> list,
        int start, 
        int n
    ) {
    
        Func<decimal,decimal,int> trueModulo = (a,b) => {
            if (a >= 0)
                return (int)(a % b);
            var roundsToPositive = Math.Ceiling(Math.Abs(Convert.ToDecimal(a) / b));
            a += Convert.ToInt32(roundsToPositive * b);
            return (int)(a % b);
        };
    
        start = trueModulo(start, list.Count);
    
        start=start%list.Count;
        List<T> range = new List<T>();
                                
        for (
            int i=start; 
            n > 0 ? i < start + n : i > start + n; // i < or > start + n?
            i += n > 0 ? 1 : -1 // step forwards or backwards?
        ) {
           range.Add(list[trueModulo(i,list.Count)]);
        }
        
        return range;
        
    }

}
```

So you can do:

```
List<char> e = new List<char>{'a','b','c','d','e','f'};

var newRange = e.GetRingedRange(4,5); // e, f, a, b, c
newRange = e.GetRingedRange(-4,5); // c, d, e, f, a
newRange = e.GetRingedRange(4,-7); // e, d, c, b, a, f, e
```

Comment: Thank you. Can your example take negative start index as well?

Comment: Sorry, I read your question as saying you already implemented this.  I edited so negative start is now possible.